# Get image based on category django drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i want to fetch image on particular category like if i make get request localhost/api/image/3/ i get 3rd category image

models.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'home/tboss/Desktop/image' , default = 'home/tboss/Desktop/image/logo.png')
      category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.title
```

view.py:

```
class ImageView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    pagination_class = None
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        cat = self.request.query_params['category']            
        return Image.objects.all().filter(category = cat)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Image
    fields = ('title','category','image')
```

api output:

```
 [
    {
        "title": "aka",
        "category": 5,
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/home/tboss/Desktop/image/logo.png"
    },
    {
        "title": "aka",
        "category": 7,
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/home/tboss/Desktop/image/DSC_9314.JPG"
    },
    {
        "title": "test",
        "category": 3,
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/home/tboss/Desktop/image/Pillars_Outdoor_OR_RD_50003619_1280x640_DQMyGuR.jpg"
    }
]
```

urls.py:

```
 path('image/', views.ImageView.as_view(), name = 'category_image'),
```

Comment: you can use retriveapiview to get individual views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: Your serializer is referencing a model (EventImage) not defined in your models.py above. Is this intentional? To me you should be referencing `Image`

You can override the queryset with something like this:

```py
class ImageView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    pagination_class = None
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
    """
    If query_param URL exists, return filtered queryset
    Else, return entire Image queryset
    """
        # assuming you need an integer, so I'm casting cat to an INT
        if 'category' in self.request.query_params:
            cat = int(self.request.query_params['category'])
            return Image.objects.all().filter(category=cat)
        return Image.objects.all()
```

`urls.py`

```py
path('image', views.ImageView.as_view(), name = 'category_image'),
```

The get your images in a category=my_category with a URL like:

`localhost/api/image?category=my_category`

**N.B.** I have no included the trailing slash at the end of the URL, largely for aesthetics and I have updated urls.py accordingly above.

This will return a list of all images matching the chosen category.

Another way of doing it is using a keyword argument in your URL.

```py
# ListAPIView returns a list of objects.
# If you just want to return a single object,
# use RetreiveAPIView
# If you want a read-writeable endpoint,
# Use ListCreateAPIView or RetrieveCreateAPIView

class MyImageView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return Image.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["cat"])
```

And in URLs, you configure it to accept a keyword argument, in the case of my code below, `cat`. This is referenced both in the view and the url.

**N.B.** That this URL must always include a a category, so you can use it in addition to other URLs you might develop.

```py
    # if you are expecting an integer, use int:cat
    # if you're expecting a string, use str:cat
    # this will be determined by the primary key type
    # of your related model. It does appear though that it is an INT.
    path('image/<int:cat>', MyImageView.as_view()), name='cat_image'),
```

You could then navigate to `localhost/api/my_categoy` where `my_category` is the name/number of your category.

Comment: Can you please provide a full stack trace of the error output. It would also be very helpful if you posted your urls.py, the image model from models.py and the image from serializers.py.

You could also try adding a traling slash to your url, for example `localhost/api/image/?category=<insert your category here>`, but difficult for me to say without seeing your urls.py

Comment: see the edits and this is the error invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10/'

Comment: Can you post your models too? I would like to see what datatype category is. It appears that it is an IntegerField and you are passing a string to it. As a test, trying casting `cat` to an int with something like `cat = int(self.request.query_params['category'])`

Comment: see the edits and now this error Expected view ImageView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly

Comment: Your serializer is referencing a model (EventImage) not defined in your models.py above. Is this intentional? To me you should be referencing Image

Comment: its working but retrieveapiview can get only one image and if i want to make a request like image/<category>/ what would be better way cause i cant add trailing slash your first answer

Comment: I've updated the answer to use ListView. Listview returns a list, RetriveView returns a single object.